# IncompatibleClassChangeError while starting the my application

Tags: java, maven, deployment, guava

I am getting the below error while i am trying to start my application on a Amazon Linux Machine.

```
Caused by: java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: class com.google.common.cache.CacheBuilder$3 has interface com.google.common.base.Ticker as super class
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error means that the bytecode for `CacheBuilder` expects `Ticker` to be a Java class but it was an interface instead.

You have two versions of Guava on the classpath OR you're starting the app with a different version of Guava that what you used to build.

Try `mvn dependency:tree` and look for duplicates. If that looks good, check the classpath when running the app on your VM.

In rare cases, someone might have been "clever" and copied the bytecode for `com.google.common.base.Ticker` (or `CacheBuilder`) into their JAR. Try a text search on all JARs to find candidates or write a unit test that prints the result of

```
getClass().getClassLoader().getResources("com/google/common/base/Ticker.class");
```

to see who likes to contribute (should return just a single URL). If that works, do the same for `CacheBuilder`.

Comment: My classpath had two versions of Guava. One was jersey-Guava-2.22.2 and guava-16.0.1 . I tried removing the previous , still facing the same issue.Also when i tried the text search, i found both of these guava versions having the ticker class. What can i probably do next.

Comment: @AnuragAnand Then please accept my answer (https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: Thank you for your response , but i am still open on my issue and i expect some inputs. Will surely accept your response , which is obviously helpful..

Comment: @AnuragAnand Look at the file names in the ZIP archives (any ZIP tool can look into JAR files). From what I saw, Jersey contains `Ticker` but with a different package name. That doesn't cause problems. Try your search again to see which JARs contain `com/google/common/cache/CacheBuilder.class`

Comment: @AnuragAnand At some point in time, Guava changed `Ticker` from `interface` to `abstract class`. See https://github.com/google/guava/commit/c87142e306811f7ac9094d43de45dca4339a2898#diff-bbc6df7453b3f231f1a2d50097443aee

Comment: `CacheBuilder` still expects the class, so that's really old code. Try to find who brings a `CacheBuilder`. In IDEs, you can try to open the type. It should then list all JARs which contain the type. Anything without "Guava" in the name is suspicious.